# Creating a progress bar when uploading files

Tags: django, file-upload, django-file-upload

I'm trying to create a progress bar when the user is uploading a file, but it is not throwing the json to create the progress bar.

I have handler.py:

```
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import FileUploadHandler
from django.core.cache import cache

class UploadProgressCachedHandler(FileUploadHandler):
"""
Tracks progress for file uploads.
The http post request must contain a header or query parameter, 'X-Progress-ID'
which should contain a unique string to identify the upload to be tracked.
"""

def __init__(self, request=None):
    super(UploadProgressCachedHandler, self).__init__(request)
    self.progress_id = None
    self.cache_key = None

def handle_raw_input(self, input_data, META, content_length, boundary, encoding=None):
    self.content_length = content_length
    if 'X-Progress-ID' in self.request.GET :
        self.progress_id = self.request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
    elif 'X-Progress-ID' in self.request.META:
        self.progress_id = self.request.META['X-Progress-ID']
    if self.progress_id:
        self.cache_key = "%s_%s" % (self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], self.progress_id )
        cache.set(self.cache_key, {
            'length': self.content_length,
            'uploaded' : 0
        })

def new_file(self, field_name, file_name, content_type, content_length, charset=None):
    pass

def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
    if self.cache_key:
        data = cache.get(self.cache_key)
        data['uploaded'] += self.chunk_size
        cache.set(self.cache_key, data)
    return raw_data

def file_complete(self, file_size):
    pass

def upload_complete(self):
    if self.cache_key:
        cache.delete(self.cache_key)
```

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^upload/$', 'home.views.upload')
url(r'^upload_progress/$','home.views.upload_progress',name="upload-progress"),
```

in settings.py:

```
from django.conf import global_settings
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ('home.handler.UploadProgressCachedHandler', ) + \
global_settings.FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS
```

in views.py:

```
def upload_progress(request):
progress_id = ''
if 'X-Progress-ID' in request.GET:
    progress_id = request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
    return progress_id

elif 'X-Progress-ID' in request.META:
    progress_id = request.META['X-Progress-ID']
if progress_id:
    from django.utils import simplejson
    cache_key = "%s_%s" % (request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], progress_id)
    data = cache.get(cache_key)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
else:
    return HttpResponseServerError('Server Error: You must provide X-Progress-ID header or query param.')

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    nombre = request.FILES['objeto'].name
    path = '/path/to/%s' % nombre
    f = request.FILES['objeto']
    destination = open(path, 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
    #....
```

in the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Generate 32 char random uuid
function gen_uuid() {
    var uuid = ""
    for (var i=0; i < 32; i++) {
        uuid += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
    }
    return uuid
}

// Add upload progress for multipart forms.
$(function() {

    $('#upload').submit(function(){
        // Prevent multiple submits

        if ($.data(this, 'submitted')) return false;

        var freq = 1000; // freqency of update in ms
        var uuid = gen_uuid(); // id for this upload so we can fetch progress info.
        var progress_url = '/upload_progress/'; // ajax view serving progress info

        // Append X-Progress-ID uuid form action
        this.action += (this.action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'X-Progress-ID=' + uuid;

        var $progress = $('<div id="upload-progress" class="upload-progress"></div>').
            appendTo(document.body).append('<div class="progress-container"><span class="progress-info">uploading 0%</span><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>');

        // progress bar position
        $progress.css({
            position: (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/6/) )? 'absolute' : 'fixed',
            left: '50%', marginLeft: 0-($progress.width()/2), bottom: '20%'
        }).show();

        // Update progress bar
        function update_progress_info() {

            alert("hola");

            $progress.show();
            $.get('/upload_progress/', { 'X-Progress-ID': uuid}, function(data, status){
                if (data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.uploaded) / parseInt(data.length);
                    var width = $progress.find('.progress-container').width()
                    var progress_width = width * progress;
                    $progress.find('.progress-bar').width(progress_width);
                    $progress.find('.progress-info').text('uploading ' + parseInt(progress*100) + '%');
                }
                window.setTimeout(update_progress_info, freq);
            });
        };




        window.setTimeout(update_progress_info, freq);

        $.data(this, 'submitted', true); // mark form as submitted.
    });
});
```

Is not working. I check the console of the browser and  is not throwing the json.
by the way, the id of my form is #upload

Comment: Why don't you use a jquery plugin for this? Uploadify for example, it has a progress bar built in.

Comment: What about the server side? actually is the main problem.

Comment: It creates the progress bar with flash, the addon fixes it all. You only have to worry about storing the file.

Comment: Flash is not for web. But thanks.